# Extracting strings in an Array format with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'll try to explain in detail as much as I can. Please forgive me if I can't explain it well. But, this is the issue I have:

1. Data is passing to our database and in a single cell, data is coming in as an array ({cat, dog, pet} e.g.)
2. I need to retrieve only two values-cat and dog.

Is there a way to do that with SQL? I can use a wildcard, but it seems like the characters and commas are affecting it.

Should I ask for it to be split into rows instead?

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YPir.png)

Comment: what sql plateform are you using and what version

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results, as tabular text, to clarify your question.

Comment: I am using MySql. Great question on the version. I would not know. I am working within Salesforce's database. I'll be adding sample data shortly.

Comment: Sample data has been added and it shows the way it is syncing.

Comment: *data is coming in as an array ({cat, dog, pet} e.g.)* This looks like JSON object. Screenshot looks like this field is JSON array. What is it really? Anycase MySQL have JSON datatype and a lot of JSON-specific fuctions. Your task seems not to be difficult.

Comment: I have to create segments based on purchases a record has made. For example, record 1 purchased a cat and a dog that will be segment A. Record 2 only purchased a cat, that will be segment B.